# How to use REGEX_EXTRACT_ALL in Pig

Tags: regex, apache-pig

This is my sample data,

```
subId=00001111911128052627,towerid=11232w34532543456345623453456984756894756,bytes=122112212212212218.4621702216543667E17
subId=00001111911128052639,towerid=11232w34532543456345623453456984756894756,bytes=122112212212212219.6726312167218586E17
subId=00001111911128052615,towerid=11232w34532543456345623453456984756894756,bytes=122112212212212216.9431647633139046E17
```

My expected output will be a tuple where each field represents a matched group:

> (capturing_group1, capturing_group2, ..., capturing_groupN)
>
> e.g.(00001111911128052627,11232w34532543456345623453456984756894756,122112212212212216.9431647633139046E17)

This is my approach,

```
A = load '/home/hduser/Desktop/arrtest1.txt' using TextLoader as (line:chararray);
b = FOREACH A GENERATE FLATTEN(REGEX_EXTRACT_ALL(line,'(.*)[subId=](.*)[towerid=](.*)[bytes=](.*)')) AS (F1,F2,F3);
```

But I am not getting my result.

Comment: You have 4 capturing groups defined, but you need only 3. Also, you are using character classes around `[subId=]`, etc. that matches 1 symbol from the set (either `s` or `u`... or `=`). `.*` is too greedy that is why the results you get are unexpected. Try `A = LOAD '/home/hduser/Desktop/arrtest1.txt' USING TEXTLOADER() AS (LINE:CHARARRAY);
b = FOREACH A GENERATE FLATTEN(
      REGEX_EXTRACT_ALL(LINE, '^subId=([^=]*)towerid=([^=]*)bytes=([^=]*)$'))
       AS (F1:CHARARRAY, F2:CHARARRAY, F3:CHARARRAY), LINE;`

Comment: @stribizhev: ``REGEX_EXTRACT_ALL`` returns a tuple with all the capturing groups, the comma ``,`` is in the data structure not in the strings extracted (i've recreated in the online demo the tuple as a string just to show a match with the desired OP result).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your input example you can try with this regex:

```
REGEX_EXTRACT_ALL(line,'subId=([^,]*),towerid=([^,]*),bytes=(.*)')
```

You can check the behaviour of this regex [at this link](https://regex101.com/r/oE5xC9/2).

**Update**: why not use `.*` to check the field?

The default greedy nature of kleene operator `*` cause the regex engine to matches till the end of the string, then it go back one char per time and to check if the next section of the regex  matches (e.g. it searches for a comma `,` after the first `.*`).

So at the end all the regex below match but with different steps to complete the process:

[`[a-zA-Z]+=(.*),[a-zA-Z]+=(.*),[a-zA-Z]+=(.*)` - 1142 steps](https://regex101.com/r/oE5xC9/3)

[`subId=([^,]*),towerid=([^,]*),bytes=(.*)` - 96 steps](https://regex101.com/r/oE5xC9/2).

If you don't care about the fields name and you want pure letters fields (uppercase or lowercase):

[`(?i)[a-z]+=([^,]*)[a-z,]+=([^,]*),[a-z,]+=(.*)` - 58 steps](https://regex101.com/r/oE5xC9/4)

*NB*: the Apache Pig regex engine is based on the Java one so the case-insensitive flag `(?i)` is likely to works too.

Comment: b = FOREACH A GENERATE FLATTEN(REGEX_EXTRACT_ALL(line,'[a-zA-Z]+=(.*),[a-zA-Z]+=(.*),[a-zA-Z]+=(.*)')) AS (F1,F2,F3); I did this way:-) thanks.

Comment: @RinkuBuragohain: this behaves differently: it does not check the name of the fields and it's slower because of the backtracking: ``.*`` matches all till the end (every time it's used) then go back to check if there is some points where the regex can match.

Comment: @RinkuBuragohain: i've updated the answer with some benchmarks about the use of ``[^,]*`` instead of ``.*``. Note the in the last one capturing groups i've used ``.*`` too cause it has to match till the end anyway