# pig script to parse aws elb log

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig, hadoop2

I am trying to parse this elb logs with pig and I am able to parse it successfully using this script

++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
    2016-07-16T00:00:41.700161Z testelb 11.11.17.2:50883 192.168.1.94:80 0.00002 0.001392 0.000019 200 200 0 43 "GET http://test.example.com:80/bac?aid=b5cf542d74&cid=etrsewtp&bid=23c45c543&dte=Sat%20Jul%2016%202016%2008:00:41%20GMT+0800%20(HKT) HTTP/1.1" "Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 9_3_2 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/601.1.46 (KHTML, like Gecko) Mobile/13F69" - -
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

```
***************************************************************
A = LOAD '/tmp/one.log' USING TextLoader AS (line:chararray);

B = FOREACH A GENERATE FLATTEN (
    REGEX_EXTRACT_ALL(
            line,'^(\\S+) (\\S+) (\\S+) (\\S+) (\\S+) (\\S+) (\\S+) (\\S+) (\\S+) (\\S+) (\\S+) "(.+?)" "(.+?)" (\\S+) (\\S+)')
    ) AS (
    timestamp:chararray, elb:int, client_port:chararray, backend_port:chararray, request_processing_time:float, backend_processing_time:float, response_processing_time:float, elb_status_code:int, backend_status_code:int, received_bytes:int, sent_bytes:int, request:chararray, user_agent:chararray, ssl_cipher:chararray, ssl_protocol:chararray
);

DUMP B;
```

---

Now I want to extract request url, aid, bid, cid etc but not able to match the regex. Can someone help me to get these details?

Apart from above regex method if there is any other method to get the complete elb log details then I would like to know.

NOTE: The position of aid, bid and cid are not fixed in the request log.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question has been already answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34492105/how-to-use-regex-extract-all-in-pig)

[Alternate way to do the same task](http://wiki.apache.org/pig/UDFManual#Load.2FStore_Functions-1) requires a custom loader.